# Объясните логику функции FROM_DAYS() в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Внимание, вопрос:
Как и при каких обстоятельствах, разработчики MySQL решили, что функция `FROM_DAYS()`, будет выдавать нормальную дату, а не `0000-00-00`, если ей отправить значение больше, чем 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нашем мире существует такое понятие, как [нулевой год](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4), а вернее его отсутствие, так у предков в то время отсутствовало понятие математического нуля. Соотвественно, после 1 г. до н.э. идет 1 г. н.э., и начинается он 366й днем, то есть, будто у нас существовал уже нулевой год (но, как уже было сказано выше, его нет!). В общем, такой парадокс выходит, поэтому, если вдруг понадобилась такая дата, как 01-01-0001, то нужно вводить `FROM_DAYS(366)`.